# Trying to compute softmax values, getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'T'

Tags: python, list, numpy, attributes, softmax

First off, here is my code:

```
"""Softmax."""

scores = [3.0, 1.0, 0.2]

import numpy as np

def softmax(x):
    """Compute softmax values for each sets of scores in x."""
    num = np.exp(x)
    score_len = len(x)
    y = [0] * score_len
    for index in range(1,score_len):
        y[index] = (num[index])/(sum(num))
    return y

print(softmax(scores))

# Plot softmax curves
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(-2.0, 6.0, 0.1)
scores = np.vstack([x, np.ones_like(x), 0.2 * np.ones_like(x)])

plt.plot(x, softmax(scores).T, linewidth=2)
plt.show()
```

Now looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741372/syntax-in-python-t) question, I can tell that T is the transpose of my list. However, I seem to be getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'T'

I do not understand what's going on here. Is my understanding of this entire situation wrong. I'm trying to get through the Google Deep Learning course and I thought that I could Python by implementing the programs, but I could be wrong. I currently know a lot of other languages like C and Java, but new syntax always confuses me.

Comment: You have a regular Python `list` object, not a `numpy.ndarray` or `numpy.matrix`. The latter may support a `.T` attribute, but Python lists don't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514553/how-to-declare-an-array-in-python Aren't lists the same as arrays in Python?

Comment: No, they are not. That question is incredibly confusing in that regard.

Comment: Python `list` objects are sequences of arbitrary length that can store any object. `array`s (as defined in C) are fixed length and can only store values of one type. Python does have a [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) where the type is a lot like the C concept. `numpy` defines another, with a lot in common with the Python standard library `array` module. You want the `numpy` definition here.

Comment: Anyway, when in doubt, [look at the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) and you'll see that there is no `.T` attribute documented.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I just put up an answer, could you make sure it's all accurate?

Comment: I don't actually do much work with numpy, I don't know if it is accurate. All I did was take a quick peek at the docs to confirm Numpy has objects with a `.T` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the type and shape of variables in your code

`x` is a 1d array; `scores` is 2d (3 rows):

```
In [535]: x.shape
Out[535]: (80,)
In [536]: scores.shape
Out[536]: (3, 80)
```

`softmax` produces a list of 3 items; the first is the number 0, the rest are arrays with shape like `x`.

```
In [537]: s=softmax(scores)
In [538]: len(s)
Out[538]: 3
In [539]: s[0]
Out[539]: 0
In [540]: s[1].shape
Out[540]: (80,)
In [541]: s[2].shape
Out[541]: (80,)
```

Were you expecting `softmax` to produce an array with the same shape as its input, in this case a `(3,80)`.

```
num=np.exp(scores)
res = np.zeros(scores.shape)
for i in range(1,3):
    res[i,:]= num[i,:]/sum(num)
```

creates a 2d array that can be transposed and plotted.

But you shouldn't have to do this row by row.  Do you really want the 1st row of `res` to be 0?

```
res = np.exp(scores)
res = res/sum(res)
res[0,:] = 0    # reset 1st row to 0?
```

Why were you doing a vectorized operation on each row of `scores`, but not on the whole thing?

Answer (score 4):

As described in the comments, it is essential that the output of `softmax(scores)` be an array, as lists do not have the `.T` attribute. Therefore if we replace the relevant bits in the question with the code below, we can access the `.T` attribute again.

```
num = np.exp(x)
score_len = len(x)
y = np.array([0]*score_len)
```

It must be noted that we need to use the `np.array` as non `numpy` libraries do not usually work with ordinary `python` libraries.