# I don't know the meaning of the code "[:, row:row]"

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have the code:

```
g, g_err = data[:, 4:6].T
```

I don't know the meaning of `[:, 4:6]`

especially the first `:`

and does `.T` mean transpose?

Comment: Search for slicing notation in numpy.

Comment: And here is an explanation for .T https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741372/syntax-in-python-t

Answer (score 1):

You have a 2D matrix called `data`, your code takes all elements from the first dimension, marked as `:`, then takes only elements `4 and 5` in the second dimension, something like this:

```
>>> np.ones( (7,7 ))
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
>>> np.ones( (7,7 ))[:,4:6]
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
>>>
```

And yeah, `.T` means transpose.